# Why does this print `3 {}` and not `2 {'a': 3}`?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, argument-unpacking

```
def f(a=2, **b):
    print(a,b)

f(**{'a':3})
```

Why does this print `3 {}` and not `2 {'a': 3}`?

I can understand why it printed `3 {}` if it was `f(a=3)` but I don't understand the output in this case.

Comment: because `f(**{'a': 3})` is equivalent to `f(a=3)` that is the point. any variables that aren't explicitly defined go to `b` and rest expand as expected.

Comment: If it helps your understanding, try `f(a=4, **{'a': 3})` -> `TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'`

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: @chris_rands I don't think that duplicate is appropriate. The question here is about sending a kwargs dict containing a kwarg that is already specified explicitly. It might not be obvious from just reading a question on using `**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unpacking operator, when used on a dict, passes the dict's contents as keyword arguments.

In other words, the following two lines are functionally identical:

```
f(a=3)
f(**{'a':3})
```

Since `a` is getting passed *explicitly* as a keyword argument, the default value of `2` is overwritten. And since no other arguments are passed, the `**b` argument is left empty.

Answer (score 1):

The call `f(**{'a':3})` is same as `f(a=3)`, so the value of `a` is 3 and not the default 2. For `b` , using the unpacking operator `**`, it means to save all the other mapping variable into it, as there is no one, it values an empty dict

- `a` is 3
- `b` is empty dict, `{}`

So it prints `3 {}`

---

To use `b` you need to pass argument named differently as `a`

```
# both print: 3 {'foo': 'bar', 'number': 100}
f(**{'a':3, 'foo':'bar', 'number':100}) 
f(a=3, foo='bar', number=100)
```